# ajax post with jquery to mongodb

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to make a Post request using jQuery to mongodb. 
running on app localhost:3000.
Using mongoose I can get to display movies using:

```
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    mongoose.model('Movie').find(function(err, titles){
      res.render('testdb', { title: 'MYMusic',
        className: 'index',
        names: titles
      });
      console.log('names: ', titles);
    });
  });
```

But when I want to dynamically post to my database using jQuery using:

```
 $('.save-video-button').on('click', function(event) {

      var obj = {
        title: 'some title'
      };

      var URL = 'mongodb://localhost/mydatabase';

      $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('success --> data :', data);

        },
        error:   function(xhr, text, err) {
          console.log('error: ',err);
          console.log('text: ', text);
          console.log('xhr: ',xhr);
          console.log("there is a problem whit your request, please check ajax request");
        }
      });

    });
```

when I run this ajax request it get an error shown in google chrome dev tools console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load mongodb://localhost/mydatabase. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

How can I avoid this cross origin request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ok I got it! for anyone with the same question DO NOT forget to have a router.post in you server side:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var newmovie = res.body;
    console.log(newmovie);
});
```

so when you make the call you can actually pass the data = res.